# Unique identifier for partition according to consecutive rows

Tags: sql, sql-server, partitioning, row-number, dense-rank

I'm working on a SQL Server query that needs partitioning in a way such that consecutive rows with the same Type value ordered by date have the same unique identifier.

Let's say I have the following table

```
declare @test table 
(
CustomerId  varchar(10),
Type INT,
date datetime
)

insert into @test values ('aaaa', 1,'2015-10-24 22:52:47')
insert into @test values ('bbbb', 1,'2015-10-23 22:56:47')
insert into @test values ('cccc', 2,'2015-10-22 21:52:47')
insert into @test values ('dddd', 2,'2015-10-20 22:12:47')
insert into @test values ('aaaa', 1,'2015-10-19 20:52:47')
insert into @test values ('dddd', 2,'2015-10-18 12:52:47')
insert into @test values ('aaaa', 3,'2015-10-18 12:52:47')
```

I want my output column to be something like this(the numbers do not need to be ordered, all I need are unique identifiers for each group) :
Edited the original post because I made a mistake on my desired output

```
0
0
1
1
2
3
4
```

Disclaimer: the customerId is not really relevant for my partitioning, if the customerIds where different for each row the output would have been the same

My current query seemed to do the trick but it fails in some cases giving the same ID to rows with different type values.

```
SELECT row_number() over(order by date) - row_number() over (partition by  Type order by date)
FROM @TEST
```

Comment: so each group mean CustomerId & Type??

Comment: No, the costumerId is not really relevant for my partitioning, if the customerIds where different for each row the output would have been the same.
Each group should be  consecutive rows with the same Type(IMPORTANT:ordered by date). Everytime there's a new type breaking the "consecutiveness" it creates a new group

Answer (score 0):

Try something like:

```
declare @test table (
    CustomerId  varchar(10),
    Type INT,
    date datetime
)
insert into @test
values
    ('aaaa', 1,'2015-10-24 22:52:47'),
    ('bbbb', 1,'2015-10-23 22:56:47'),
    ('cccc', 2,'2015-10-22 21:52:47'),
    ('dddd', 2,'2015-10-20 22:12:47'),
    ('aaaa', 1,'2015-10-19 20:52:47'),
    ('dddd', 2,'2015-10-18 12:52:47'),
    ('aaaa', 3,'2015-10-18 12:52:47')
;

with cte as (
    select *, newtype = case when Type <> lag(Type) over(order by date desc) then 1 else 0 end
    from @test
)
select *,
    Result = sum(newtype) over(
        order by date desc
        rows between unbounded preceding and current row
        )
from cte
order by date desc
```

Results:

| CustomerId | Type | date | newtype | Result |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| aaaa | 1 | 2015-10-24 22:52:47.000 | 0 | 0 |
| bbbb | 1 | 2015-10-23 22:56:47.000 | 0 | 0 |
| cccc | 2 | 2015-10-22 21:52:47.000 | 1 | 1 |
| dddd | 2 | 2015-10-20 22:12:47.000 | 0 | 1 |
| aaaa | 1 | 2015-10-19 20:52:47.000 | 1 | 2 |
| dddd | 2 | 2015-10-18 12:52:47.000 | 1 | 3 |
| aaaa | 3 | 2015-10-18 12:52:47.000 | 1 | 4 |

The common table expression (CTE) flags rows where Type has changed from the prior. (The comparison to LAG()=NULL for the first row is not flagged as a change.) The main query then uses a windowed SUM to count them up.

See this [db<>fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlserver_2019&fiddle=1dcf0f882f56ef72282f42e0893398e3) for a demo.